# Nuxt: redirecting to dynamic page not working propertly

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

i have a menu component that has a function that goes to a _slug page, this is the code (i try to simplify in the code as max as i can):

```
<template>
  <input @keydown.enter="search" type="text" v-model="term" id="groupId" placeholder="Pesquisar"
                class="rounded-lg pl-10 bg-[#E6E6E6] text-[#818181] h-7">
</template>

<script lang="ts">

export default {
  name: 'Products',
  data(): {} {
    return {};
  },
  async mounted() {
    this.get()
  },
  methods: {
    search() {
      const searchUrl = `/search/${this.term}`;
      try {
        this.$router.push(searchUrl);
        console.log(this.term);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
      console.log(this.term)
    },
    async get() {
      // this function querys to the database but dont interfere in my question (i think)
    },
  }

}
</script>
```

the search function works if im already in a search _slug (that i provide in a url), like:

`http://localhost:3000/search/thingthatisearched`

the search _slug code simplified is this:

```
<template>
// shows all the products
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
    name: 'Products',
    data(): { products: Product[] } {
        return { products: [] };
    },
    async mounted() {
        this.get()
    },
    methods: {
        async get() {
            // query to database
        },
    }

}

</script>
```

but in the another pages, like the main page, that is this (in all pages the term value is getting fine in the console.log):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Menu></Menu>
    <MainBanner></MainBanner>
    <Products></Products>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">

export default ({
  name: 'IndexPage',
})

</script>
```

the search function in the menu component dont work, and i already try to remove all the components and lets only the menu, still not working, the behavior of the page looks like this (in all pages that are not already a search _slug):

the main url:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

redirects fine to the search _slug:

```
http://localhost:3000/search/thingthatisearched
```

but then the url turns this (in mili seconds):

```
http://localhost:3000/?
```

and then came back to the main page:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

someone know why the function is working only in the search _slug and the reason of another pages behavior?

Comment: There's nothing in this code that could cause this. Try to look if you have any middlewares in between that could cause a redirect?

Comment: i solve it by using a nuxt link to redirect instead of a function.